# error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66:

Tags: 20.04, nodejs

I’ve installed Node and NPM but every time I use it I get this error `error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66:` any ideas running Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS, everything else working fine..

Comment: I done that, just shows no output and when I run the command shows the same error?

Comment: Tried them still nothink..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the package [which provides this *libicui18n.so* library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libicui18n.so.6) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libicu66
```

Comment: Hi Norbert: Thanks for above but do you know if the name  libicu66 changed since you answered because I'm getting "libicui18n.so.71: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".  But the second command above says that it's unable to locate libicu66.